# (I think) A mistake in the Hölder Inequality proof In Royden's real analysis(3ed).

Tags: real-analysis

In Royden's real analysis(3ed),page 121,it says that   \begin{equation} ptf(x)g(x) = ptf(x)h(x)^{p-1} \leq (h(x)+tf(x))^p - h(x)^p
\end{equation}
hence  .... ...differentiate both sides with respect to t at t=0 ,we get \begin{equation}p\int |fg| \leq p||f||_p \cdot ||h||_p^{p-1}
.\end{equation}
In other words,if \begin{equation} H(t) \leq L(t),\end{equation}
then \begin{equation} H'(t) \leq L'(t).\end{equation}
But the statemengt is clearly wrong.Do you agree with me?

Comment: But if $H(0)=L(0)$ and $H(t)\le L(t)$ for $t\ge 0$, then it follows from the definition of the derivative that $H'(0)\le L'(0)$, which seems to be all he's claiming.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I am confused. The two lines "$H(t)\le L(t)$" and "$H'(t)\le L'(t)$" are only the OP's interpretation. They do not appear in the 3/e of Royden. In view of Ted's comment, would you please turn your comment into an answer and explain *what* the error is (if any) and *how* it is corrected in the 4/e?

Comment: @user1551 The interpretation above is the one I have seen referenced before as an error.  Ted (and the book) is correct, though.  I was wrong.  To answer your second question, I was told (but have not verified) the the 4/e has one the standard proofs of Holder in it.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks for the clarification.